# Nodejs swig, substring or limit chars

Tags: javascript, node.js, swig-template

Is there any way to limit string? Example:

```
{{item | limit(50)}}
```

Or maybe substring function?

Comment: You might also find this helpful:  https://gist.github.com/soomtong/5465409

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't exactly a filter that does that out of the box, but you can do it using replace.

```
{{ item | replace("^(.{50,50})(.*)", "$1") }}
```

This creates a RegExp that captures the first 50 characters ( any character: '.' between 50 and 50 times '{50,50}' ) then puts it in $1 and anything left goes in rest as $2. Then you replace the result with just $1... essentially throwing $2 away. It's a bit odd looking, but it will do the job.